How to return data promise with funtion from looping parameter data
How can i return this promise data in template with function and parameter data looping?
this was my code:
  let data = [
    {
      id: 1,
      model: "DIY-MULTI3-27HP230C"
    }
  ]

  const getByModelNo = async ({ id, params }: { id: string, params?: AxiosRequestConfig }) => {
    const options = {
      method: 'GET',
      url: `${prefix}/${id}`,
      params
    };
    let data: DataFromModel | any = {};
    try {
      const response = await axios.request(options);
      data = response?.data?.data
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching configurator-post:', error);
    }
    return data;
  }
  )

i want the result can return like this example:
  return(
   <div>
     {data.map((items, index) => (
        <div key={index}>{getByModelNo({id: items.model}).seriesName }</div>
       )
     )}
   </div>


You should not have to wait for promises in the render function. See Rendering React components with promises inside the render method

You can leverage the new use API in React 19, but you have to create the promises before render.
